# How to integrate facebook account with asp.net web site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, facebook

Hi I have integrated Facebook with asp.net web site through open id But now it is not working . I think Facebook change process of authentication.

So there is any way to integrate Facebook account with asp.net web site . Please suggest me usable link or samples.

Comment: What does your code look like? How does it not work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend the [Facebook C# sdk](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) which provides support for the full breadth of the API and is frequently updated. It also has quite a good bit of documentation (which I won't re-print here, since it would be specific to the library and if the link moved or the library went away, wouldn't have any value)

If *all* you want to integrate is auth, I would *still* recommend using the library if for no other reason an it handles the signing part for you, and gives you room to do more in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't use OpenID, they use OAuth 2.

Oldish, but I think still accurate for Asp.Net
http://osnapz.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/using-asp-net-with-facebooks-graph-api-and-oauth-2-0-authentication/

Here's another for MVC3
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/net_mvc_facebook_oauth.aspx

Comment: While your article may in fact answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Stack Overflow is only as useful as its questions and answers, and if your blog host goes down or your URLs get moved around, this answer becomes useless. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Gigya](http://www.gigya.com/social-login/) they provide free services through you can put social authentication to your website. But in free service their little backlink comes but for premium users there is no backlink.

Comment: While your article may in fact answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Stack Overflow is only as useful as its questions and answers, and if your blog host goes down or your URLs get moved around, this answer becomes useless. Thanks!